# Converting a fisheye image to landscape and diving it into four parts using c#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have an fisheye image and what I am trying to do is convert it into landscape.
The code I have written converts it into landscape but when it comes to divding it into different parts it adds black parts to them.

Can anyone help

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace fisheye_image
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // assume the source image is square, and its width has even number of pixels
            Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\lillestromfisheye.jpg");

        int l = bm.Width / 2;
        int i, j;
        int x, y;
        double radius, theta;
        // calculated indices in Cartesian coordinates with trailing decimals
        double fTrueX, fTrueY;
        int iSourceWidth = (2 * l);

        int run = 0, lastWidth = 1;


        while (run<4)
        {
            Bitmap bmDestination = new Bitmap(lastWidth*l, l);
            for (i = 0; i < bmDestination.Height; ++i)
            {
                radius = (double)(l - i);

                for (j = run*l; j < lastWidth*l ; ++j)
                {
                    // theta = 2.0 * Math.PI * (double)(4.0 * l - j) / (double)(4.0 * l);
                    theta = 2.0 * Math.PI * (double)(-j) / (double)(4.0 * l);

                    fTrueX = radius * Math.Cos(theta);
                    fTrueY = radius * Math.Sin(theta);

                    // "normal" mode
                    x = (int)(Math.Round(fTrueX)) + l;
                    y = l - (int)(Math.Round(fTrueY));
                    // check bounds
                    if (x >= 0 && x < iSourceWidth && y >= 0 && y < iSourceWidth)
                    {
                        bmDestination.SetPixel(j, i, bm.GetPixel(x, y));
                    }
                }
            }
            bmDestination.Save(@"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\fisheyelandscape"+run.ToString()+".jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            run++;
            lastWidth++;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Below are the original and processed images

[image] [image] [image]
[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to add another variable 'k' in the second for loop that goes from zero to the width of destination image.

```
    while (run<4)
        {
            Bitmap bmDestination = new Bitmap(l, l);

            for (i = 0; i < bmDestination.Height; ++i)
            {
                radius = (double)(l - i);

                for (j = run * l, k = 0; j < lastWidth * l||k < bmDestination.Width; ++j, ++k)
                {
                    // theta = 2.0 * Math.PI * (double)(4.0 * l - j) / (double)(4.0 * l);
                    theta = 2.0 * Math.PI * (double)(-j) / (double)(4.0 * l);

                    fTrueX = radius * Math.Cos(theta);
                    fTrueY = radius * Math.Sin(theta);

                    // "normal" mode
                    x = (int)(Math.Round(fTrueX)) + l;
                    y = l - (int)(Math.Round(fTrueY));
                    // check bounds
                    if (x >= 0 && x < iSourceWidth && y >= 0 && y < iSourceWidth)
                    {
                        bmDestination.SetPixel(k, i, bm.GetPixel(x, y));
                    }
                }
```